No visoble networks after the pc wakes up
I have dual booted my system with windows and ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS  loaded.
Whenever I open my laptop after I had put it into sleep mode, it detects no visible networks.
The issue resolves when I restart the pc but this make me slow as I have to first save all my work and then restart the pc.
Is there a way to solve it?

This only happens on ubuntu os

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
